# Can not get return type of my function with string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, wcf

So guys, I try to call my function from my web service which has the return type `List<string[]>`:

```
SQLService.SQLServiceClient proxy = new SQLService.SQLServiceClient();
List<string[]> objekte = await proxy.GetObjekteAsync();
```

but then I get this error:

> The "`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection< System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection< string>>`" type can not
>   be converted to `System.Collections.Generic.List< string[]>`

Here is my function `GetObjekte()`:

```
public List<string[]> GetObjekte()
{
    List<string[]> objektliste = new List<string[]>();
    sqlcon.Open();

    SqlCommand getObjekte = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [demo]", sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader reader = getObjekte.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string[] stringarry = new string[3];

        stringarry[1] = reader["Beschreibung"].ToString();
        stringarry[2] = reader["Lief_ an Adresse"].ToString();
        stringarry[3] = Convert.ToString(reader["Lief_ an PLZ-Code"] + " " + reader["Lief_ an Ort"]);

        objektliste.Add(stringarry);
    }
    sqlcon.Close();

    return objektliste;
}
```

I don't know why Visual Studio thinks that it has a:

> `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection< string>>`

as a return type... I don't see my mistake here. Maybe some of u can help me...

Whole code of my webservice class:

```
namespace SQLService

public class SQLService : ISQLService
{

    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server=; Database=; Uid=; Pwd=");

    public List<string[]> GetObjekte()
    {
        List<string[]> objektliste = new List<string[]>();
        sqlcon.Open();

        SqlCommand getObjekte = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [demo]", sqlcon);
        SqlDataReader reader = getObjekte.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] stringarry = new string[3];

            stringarry[1] = reader["Beschreibung"].ToString();
            stringarry[2] = reader["Lief_ an Adresse"].ToString();
            stringarry[3] = Convert.ToString(reader["Lief_ an PLZ-Code"] + " " + reader["Lief_ an Ort"]);

            objektliste.Add(stringarry);
        }
        sqlcon.Close();

        return objektliste;
    }
}
```

my interface:

```
namespace SQLService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISQLService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string[]> GetObjekte();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are adding an array to a list?  am not sure how that is even compiling `objektliste.Add(stringarry);` Probably you copy pasted it wrongly , it should look like `objektliste.AddRange(stringarry);` Can you ensure you have the right code in your question

Comment: No, that is not the problem, I am adding a string[] to my list with that. It mean each item in my list is one string[] - but i just had a type on my variable, it was to meant stringarray

Comment: if you say what you have is right, my 1 cent it wont compile and am afraid you are wrong. that line would NOT compile - look more closely - it should say `AddRange` and not `Add`

Comment: wait, ill provide u a screenshot :D

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9gDU4G - here is what I mean

Comment: may u need to look more closely. my list is not type of **List<string>** - it is **List<string[]>** - but nice try (;

Comment: here is what I mean https://dotnetfiddle.net/pxb3Kx

Comment: oops, yes, I did not check the return type closely. let me see what else am missing

Comment: ok ,np thank you anyway for helping me

Comment: So  you enconter this error during run time? or does it show up on compile time -? also can you please add the class names around each of the methods above? is your client code a WPF/console app? are they all on the same solution? is there an overload etc

Comment: Most like the generated proxy does not have the same return type of `List<string[]>` so it is erroring out.

Comment: I get the error while compiling, and i will add this in a minute

Comment: @CodingYoshi - it has the same return type as u can see, i will also add the code of interface too (wich also got the same return type)...

Comment: No I am not talking about that code. I am talking about the proxy code: Put the cursor on this method name and press F12 and see what the return type is: `await proxy.GetObjekteAsync();`

Comment: For some reason it is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>>`

Comment: Maybe it is because of the `Async()` at the end of my method

Comment: @dennisanberlin, When you generate the client it generates Observable collections on the client side for all collections returned from the service. That is something you set when first creating the web service client in the project.

Comment: @Nkosi And how can I change it?

Comment: @dennisanberlin you are going to have to remove the current service and add it back this time when adding it look for the setting that ask for how collections should be returned.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/data-tools/configure-service-reference-dialog-box

Comment: @dennisanberlin, when adding the service reference click the `Advance...` button and set the `Collection type`. Do note that all collections exposed by the service will be generated to that collection type. dictionaries has it own setting as well

Comment: we are getting closer, now im getting this: `The "<System.Collections.Generic.List< System.Collections.Generic.List< string>>" type can not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List< string[]>`

Comment: @dennisanberlin Do note that all collections exposed by the service will be generated to that collection type. dictionaries has it own setting as well. So what you are describing is by design

Comment: @dennisanberlin to avoid problems just use `var`, ie `var objekte = await proxy.GetObjekteAsync();`

Comment: ok this is like a temporary fix, because at the end I want to get the string[] out of my List...

Comment: why are you so focused on the string array?

Comment: Because Visual Studio is just ignoring the [] atm. And I want to read the [1],[2],[3] for example.

Comment: I don´t get any error with this but it is not an string array... `List<List<string>> objekte = await proxy.GetObjekteAsync();`

Comment: @dennisanberlin lists allow indexing as well so do most other collections.

Comment: Yes, but I need 3 values for each index in the List...

Comment: @dennisanberlin which the service allows. If you want it fixed length then
 use arrays.

Comment: @Nkosi Yea this is what I try, as u can see...

Comment: @dennisanberlin i am referring to the collection type when generating service client. Right this comment thread is long enough already, I have provided as much help as I can.

Comment: @Nkosi - ah ok, but when I change it to *System.Array* I get the **string[][]** instead of my **List<string[]>**

Comment: @Nkosi Can I somehow combine the collection type?

Comment: @dennisanberlin I am telling you now that you wont be able to get `List<string[]>`, deal with it. Using another type that provides the same functionality will allow you to continue coding. If you want to waste time fretting about a specific return type then use a more flexible service that would give greater control of managing the client. Other wise all that is left is for you to transform what is returned into your desired type. Which IMO is repeating unnecessary code.

Comment: @dennisanberlin, When you get a `string[][]` call `ToList` extension on that and you will end up with a `List<string[]>`

Comment: @Nkosi It has no `ToList` Extension

Comment: @dennisanberlin add `using System.Linq` to file. How well do you know the language?

Comment: @Nkosi  `using System.Linq;` is in my file ...

Comment: @dennisanberlin I just tested a proof `string[][] array = new string[0][]; List<string[]> list = array.ToList();` and it works fine.

Comment: It is a **Task<string[][]>**

Comment: @Nkosi And Visual Studio tells me that it **.ToList()** is not an extension for the **GetObjekteAsync()** method

Comment: @dennisanberlin `List<string[]> objekte = (await proxy.GetObjekteAsync()).ToList();` you have to first unwrap the task before calling `ToList`

Comment: @Nkosi that made the trick, thank u very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update service reference to generate collection types as `System.Array`

Then update client code...

```
var proxy = new SQLService.SQLServiceClient();
List<string[]> objekte = (await proxy.GetObjekteAsync()).ToList();
```